# Opening port on Comcast modem/router connected to Netgear Prosafe firewall

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding

I've been unsuccessful in opening ports on my static IP address. Add advice on my setup would be appreciated.

Static IP -> Comcast Modem -> Firewall -> Group Computers (Windows Firewall)

**Comcast Modem/Router: DPC3939B**

- Bridge mode: disabled
- Firewall: disabled
- Port forwarding: disabled
- Port triggering: disabled
- Port management: Disable all rules and allow all inbound traffic through
- DMZ: disabled
- NAT: disable all

**Netgear Firewall: Prosafe FVS336Gv3**

- NAT: enabled
- Added a service TCP/UDP 5060 to 5060

[image]

- Added a firewall rule for that service

[image]

**Windows Firewall: disabled**

Checking that port 5060 is open results in a timeout.
http://canyouseeme.org/

Comment: Is you Prosafe router getting a public IP address from Comcast? You typically have to set the Comcast router in Bridged Mode for this to occur

Comment: The Prosafe is using the static IP from Comcast. I was unable to get the Comcast modem to work in bridge mode with static IP so I'm using "pseudo" bridge mode. http://forums.businesshelp.comcast.com/t5/Equipment-Modems-Gateways/How-to-enable-bridge-mode-on-DPC3939B-and-keep-static-IPs/td-p/20409

Comment: So this is your firewall rule, do you have a port forwarding or virtual server rule as well? Having it open in the firewall does not forward it to any internal IP address, it just allows the traffic, but without something to respond on the inside your port checker will not show anything.

Comment: have you looked at this: http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1002/~/port-forwarding-on-the-fvs318v3 it is the same configuration you need to use on your router

Comment: Yes the firewall rule in the image was created using the port forwarding guide you've linked. The "service" that I hid defines the port.

Comment: OK... And is your SIP server or client running so there is something to respond on port 5060? Does your SIP service work or haven't you tried yet?